# How to color lowest volume candle when volume bars below volume SMA in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, indicator

Im trying to code barcolor() function to mark lowest volume candle from those who below the volume(SMA,5), im tried Matrix, built_in functions eg. ta.lowest(), arrays (actually almost near my target but something wrong due to some bars marked wrongly or ignored by code or in some instances marked correctly) and so many staff, only im able to do is color all candles that corresponds all volume bars below volume(SMA,5) thats actually simple to do, below part of code  with arrays and also im attaching screenshot of the result.

```
//@version=5
cond = ma > vol
var float min_volume = na
length = ta.barssince(cond) 

Vol_array = array.new_float(500, 0)

for i = 0 to 499
    if cond
        min_volume := vol < vol[i] ? vol : na
        for j = 0 to length
            array.fill(Vol_array, min_volume[j])
min_array_vol = array.min(Vol_array)

//barcolor(cond ? color.rgb(216, 8, 119) : na)
barcolor(min_array_vol == vol ? color.blue : na)
```

[image]

So the result should be: lowest volume bar below the series of volumes under SMA should be accounted and marked

Comment: Need clarification, are you looking to mark the candles that have volume under the latest sma volume or the sma volume at the time of the candle? For example, bar 1000, if the volume is under the sma volume at bar 1000 then that is the target to color, OR bar 1000 if that volume is under the sma volume of the current real time (latest) bar?

Comment: Good day, Thanks for Your interest in this question, none of those you said actually, code should find in First: places where volume bars less than vol SMA and after it should find minimum volume bar in this areas and mark only 1 candle in which that volume was found, because if we have 5 volume bars under the SMA there will be only 1 bar that will be the minimum volume bar and this candle should be marked.

Comment: wouldn't that simple be the lowest volume bar of the entire data set, below the SMA is kind of a given is it not?  if it is the lowest volume bar in the dataset then it will be below the SMA, so you're lookoing for the bar with the lowest volume?

Comment: "so you're looking for the bar with the lowest volume?" - Yes :) but not for entire dataset and not for fixed time window it useless + it should be below SMA this requirement made for reason because sense of it to show me zones(candles) that was not filled with buys or sells properly by someone,  and reason why i need this just simplify my work not scrolling all volume indicator to search this places , just want it to point my attention on proper candle where this condition is met, I will show you what i need with the link to TradingView chart  https://www.tradingview.com/x/9FUT8AfY/

Comment: ok i see the chart, but what is the window? is it when the volume crossed below the SMA find the lowest until it crosses back over?

Comment: "is it when the volume crossed below the SMA find the lowest until it crosses back over? " - Yes thats correct and actually what i need , im tried this method but cannot figure out full logic

Comment: posted a suggestion in the answer block

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you are attempting to do, then this is the easiest way to determine the minimum volume in the segment where volume is less than the SMA(5) of the volume.

the segment volume is now set and the bar_index (not the offset) is also now set. How you use that data is up to you.

```
var float running_min_vol = 0.0
var int running_min_vol_idx = 0
var float min_vol_segment= 0.0
var int min_vol_segment_idx =0
sma_v = ta.sma(volume,5)

if ta.crossunder(volume,sma_v)
    min_vol := volume
    min_vol_idx: bar_index

min_vol := math.min(min_vol,volume)

if nz(ta.change(min_vol))<0
    min_vol_idx := bar_index

if ta.crossover(volume,sma_v)
    min_vol_segment:= min_vol
    min_vol_segment_idx := min_vol_idx
```

Comment: Okay, im tried various staff with this block that you provided, but it colors candles that only crosssed the SMA , can you try to implement your block to the piece of my code above? and second question which varible in your block will be trigger for barcolor function?

Comment: all my block did was provide you with the location (bar_index) of the minimum volume candle when the volume was below the sma. It does no coloring, that can however be done in more script. i do not know what condition you are using to color the bars and how you coded it with the right offset to the location of the bar

Comment: until the volume crosses back over the SMA you will not know the minimum bar, so there will be a delay in coloring, barcolor takes an offset. If the index for the minimum bar is min_vol_segment_idx, then the offset would be ```(bar_index - min_vol_segment_idx-1)``` for barcolor. The condition for coloring should be when volume crosses back over, ```cond= ta.crossover(volume,sma_v)```